# Inverse of certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $x\neq 0$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $a \in \mathbb{R}$. What is the determinant of the matrix
$$|x|^2\cdot \mathrm{id} + a \,x \otimes x,$$
where $a>-1$, and how to calculate it?

Comment: What is $\zeta$? $|x|^{2}$ is a scalar so to make sense of the determinant you have to be more clear about the other term.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $x$ instead of $\xi$ (there was no $\zeta$ at any time). I also clarified that by $|x|^2$, I mean a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: Kofi, the first thing that occurs to me is to work out, by brute force, what happens when $n=2$ or $n=3$. Have you done that? Showing what happens when $n=2$ would surely appease the users who may otherwise feel critical about "lack of context".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick an orthonormal (and correctly oriented) basis where $x/\left|x\right|$ is the first basis vector, then

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\left|x\right|^2+a\left|x\right|^2 & 0 &\dots & 0\\
0 & \left|x\right|^2 &\dots & 0\\
\vdots &  &\ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 &\dots & \left|x\right|^2\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
is our matrix, so the determinant is $(a+1)\left|x\right|^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $  A:= |x|^2I +axx^T$ and $\{ e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be an orthonormal set where $e_1=x/|x|$ Then $$ i>1,\ Ae_k=|x|^2e_k$$

and $$ Ae_1=(a+1)|x|^2 e_1$$

Hence we have $n$-eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: Is that nice or what! +1, of course!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to compute this is to use [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem) which says that $\det(I+AB)=\det(I+BA)$ whenever $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix and $B$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. Note that swapping $A$ and $B$ changes the dimension from $n$ to $m$.

Here we have $A=\tfrac{a}{\left|x\right|^2}x^T$ and $B=x$ so that
$$\det(\left|x\right|^2I+ax^Tx)=\left|x\right|^{2n}\det(I+\tfrac{a}{\left|x\right|^2}x^Tx)=\left|x\right|^{2n}\det(I+\tfrac{a}{\left|x\right|^2}xx^T)=\left|x\right|^{2n}(1+a)$$
where the last equality holds because the determinant of a $1\times 1$ matrix is itself.